# Macro: Search for a Text Values in a Column 1 and Copy Values to Column 2

Tags: excel, vba

Background:

Column A in "Sheet1" consists of 6,000+ rows of words separated by commas in each row. I also have a Search Word Table ("Sheet2").

Ask:

The Search Word Table ("Sheet2") consists of 24 words that I would like to identify in Column A from "Sheet1" and copy over to Column B of the same spreadsheet.

The issue I am running into is that I am dealing with a range of words (24) that I would like to cross-check each row against in Column A, and I am not sure how to set-up that up.

If the text appears at all within a string in a cell in Column A, it should pull into the same row in Column B, separated by commas. Only the text in the Search Word Table should appear in Column B.

Please help!

Comment: In VBA, just split the rows in sheet1 by commas, then check it against the words in your search word table.  Or use regular expressions

Comment: Create an array of the 24 words, loop through the array and using `InStr` check to see if it's in the column. If it is, change the cells value in Column B to the value of Column B + the comma and the value from the array.

Comment: Thanks @dwirony and @ron-rosenfeld! Can you please show me the VBA script you would use for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

The only downside with this is that you have to enter the words you're looking for into the array (see Word1, Word2, etc.)

```
Sub movingvalues()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow As Integer

Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim mywords As Variant, word As Variant
mywords = Array("Word1", "Word2", "Word3", "Word4", "Word5") 'etc all the way to Word24

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").ClearContents

For i = 1 To lastrow
    For Each word In mywords
        If InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value, word) Then
            If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value <> "" Then
                ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value & " " & word
            Else
                ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value = word
            End If
        End If
    Next word
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @dwirony. Amazing! It worked! I tested using 6 out of the 24 words, and am entering the rest into the array now. Quick question - is there a way to add a "button" into Sheet1, so that I can simply update the array in the future and hit "Search" in Sheet1?

Comment: @Walle0786 Good to hear. And yes, you can add a button. In excel if you go to the developer tab, insert, and under ActiveXControl select the little rectangular box (and then draw the button somewhere on your screen where you want it). You can then right click that button, go to assign macro, and then assign the macro you've just created to it.